# Sorting an array according to another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort one array same as other array like in this example.

```
Input : 

2 1 5 4 9 3 6 7 10 8

A B C D E F G H I J

Output : 

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

B A F D C G H J E I
```

Here is code in c++ but I don't know c++ so if someone can write it in js I would be very greatful
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-array-according-another-array-using-pair-stl/

Answer (score 1):

You could take the indices of an array, sort by the wanted order and map the values with their index.

```js
var order = [2, 1, 5, 4, 9, 3, 6, 7, 10, 8],
    values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
    result = [...order.keys()]
        .sort((a, b) => order[a] - order[b])
        .map(i => values[i]);

console.log(...result);
```